# Различная адаптивная верстка сайта на React.js под каждый вид устройства

Tags: reactjs, вёрстка, frontend, адаптивная-верстка

Как сделать так чтобы к примеру для мобильной версии сайта был один интерфейс, а для компьютерной версии другой?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеку [react-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive) чтобы определить размер экрана и на основе него менять компоненты и дизайн.

Так же для стилей можете использовать [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) который поддерживает медиа-запросы.

В остальном всё как в обычной верстке.